# Continuous mouse click event

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Is there any event generated by continuous mouse click i.e., not releasing the mouse button 1? If no, please let me know.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with Java, so I've removed that tag. Replace it if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 21):

The `mousedown` event is triggered when the mouse button is pressed down. If you are looking for an event that fires repeatedly, while the button is held down, you are out of luck, but you can use the `mousedown` event to repeatedly perform an action, and stop when the `mouseup` event is triggered.

For example, you could use the `setInterval` function to repeatedly call a function while the mouse button is down, and then use `clearInterval` to stop when the mouse button is released. Here is an example (using jQuery):

```
var interval;
$("#elementToClick").mousedown(function() {
    interval = setInterval(performWhileMouseDown, 100);
}).mouseup(function() {
    clearInterval(interval);  
});
function performWhileMouseDown() {
    $("#output").append("<p>Mouse down</p>");
}
```

You can see this running in this [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w2Vzu/3/).

Comment: Thank you. Actually I am using wicket and trying to get an ajaxEvent by which I can perform some server side execution.

Comment: Note that this does not account for when the user `mousedown`'s on the target element, but then moves their mouse off the element and `mouseup`'s somewhere else. In this case, the `performWhileMouseDown` will continue to fire indefinitely. To solve this, you can instead bind to the `document`'s `mouseup` event instead: http://jsfiddle.net/An2as/

Comment: @BillDami You could also just set the element's `mouseout` event to clearInterval.  Then both `mouseup` and `mouseover` stop the repeating.  Just in case you want a `mouseup` event for another element.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [JQuery plugin: LongClick](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/longclick)

Longclick is press & hold mouse button "long click" special event for jQuery 1.4.x.

The event is triggered when the mouse button stays pressed for a (configurable) number of seconds, while the pointer is stationery.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this using `onmousemove= movefunction(event)` :

What I did to solve this is the following:

First, create a `onmousedown()` event that sets a global variable to `1` when triggered.

Second, create a `onmouseup()` event that sets that global variable to `0` when triggered.

Then, use the `onmousemove()` event to trigger in the div where I want the mouse down behavior to occur but only if the global variable we set earlier is set to `1`.

example on how to use `onmousemove()`: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onmousemove

Done.

Answer (score 1):

There is not such event.

What you might implement to achieve this is a function that evaluates the time elapsed between the (first) mouse click ond the following mouse release.

Given a predefined range you can estabilish how long should the button be clicked before being considered valid in your logic.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-MouseEvent),

> A click is defined as a mousedown and
>   mouseup over the same screen location.
>   The sequence of these events is:
>   mousedown, mouseup, click

So no, there isn't a "continuous click", because a click is a descrete event resulting from a sequence of actions.

What you probably want to do, is receive mousedown, set a timer, and if neither mouseup or mousemove occur within some time, invoke some behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

There's a function I've been using to determine if an object is being dragged (if for some reason you cannot use the regular on drag event). Can't be certain that $(':focus')[0] === undefined will work for every situation, but it can be customized.

```
// this function will set up a mouse drag event and also check if something is being dragged
function customOnDrag(selector) {
   var dragInProgress = false;
   let mouseDrag = false;
   let mouseDown = false;
   $(selector).on('mousedown', function(event) {
       mouseDrag = false;
       mouseDown = true;
       interval = setInterval(checkIfDraggingAnObject, 20, event); // set to check every 20 ms
   }
   ).on('mousemove', function(event) {
       if ( mouseDown ){
           mouseDrag = true;
       }
   }
   ).on('mouseup', function(event) { 
       checkIfDraggingAnObject(event);
       clearInterval(interval);
       mouseDrag = false;
       mouseDown = false;
     }
  ); 
  // function to check if an object is being dregged:
  function checkIfDraggingAnObject(event){
     if ( event.type === 'mousedown' ){
        if ( $(':focus')[0] === undefined || mouseDrag === false ){
           // not dragging an object
           dragInProgress = false;   
        }else{
           // dragging an object
           dragInProgress = true;
           console.log('dragging: ');
           console.log($(':focus'));  // the object being dragged
        };
     }else if ( event.type === 'mouseup'  ) {
        if ( dragInProgress ){
           // dropped the object
           console.log('dropped: ');
           console.log($(':focus')); // the dropped object
           dragInProgress = false;
        }else if ( mouseDrag ) {
           // dragged the mouse, but no object
           console.log('did not drag an object');
        }else{
           // did not drag the mouse
           console.log('did not drag the mouse');
        }

     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class App {
    private static final int key = InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
        Robot robot;
        while (1==1) {
            try {
                robot = new Robot();
                robot.mousePress(key);
                robot.mouseRelease(key);
                // robot.mouseMove(x, y);// x,y are cordinates
                // Simulate a mouse click
                robot.mousePress(key);
                robot.mouseRelease(key);
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                // Simulate a key board press
                // robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
                // robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some comments to your code about what it does and how does it answers the question.

Comment: above code is used to continuous right click event